# Passing value in a url in php

Tags: php, url, dynamic, syntax, action

I know that one can pass a value in a url when the submit button is clicked like:
`action= assignastemp.php?value1=a` and then retrieve it in assignastemp file using `$query=$_GET['value1'];` so that $query would take the value a.

Now, check out the following:

I have this line of code in my assignastemp file so that i can retrieve the professor id in the variable `$query: $query=$_POST['searchprofid'];`

In the action field of assignastemp i have put: `action= 'sendmail.php?prof_id=$query`' since **i want that this same professor id be passed to my next form sendmail.php** so that i can also display and use it in sendmail.php. But it is not passing the value. **Please tell me the correct syntax**.

Here's my **search.php** file (it works fine and gives me proper results, but does not pass prof_id to assignastemp.php):

```
<?php
include('connectionfile.php');

    $query=$_POST['searchprofid'];
    $query1 = $_POST['searchprofname']; 
    $query2=$_POST['searchprofdesignation'];
    $query3=$_POST['searchprofexperience'];
    $query4=$_POST['searchprofemail'];
    $query5=$_POST['searchprofcolg'];
    $query6=$_POST['searchprofsubject'];


    echo "<br><p>";

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professor  WHERE (`prof_id` LIKE '%".$query."%') AND (`prof_name` LIKE '%".$query1."%')  AND (`designation` LIKE '%".$query2."%')  AND (`experience` LIKE '%".$query3."%')  AND (`prof_email_id` LIKE '%".$query4."%')  AND (`college_name` LIKE '%".$query5."%') AND (`subject_name` LIKE '%".$query6."%') ") OR die(mysql_error());

    $number= mysql_num_rows($raw_results);
    echo "<br>No. of results returned: ";
    echo "$number";

if($number > 0)
{

     echo ( "<form id='assign' action= 'assignastemp.php?prof_id=$query' method='post'> <table border='1' cellpadding='8' cellspacing= '6' bgcolor= 'white' bordercolor='158bee' align='center' >" ) ; 
            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {           
                echo ("<tr><td><p>".$results['prof_id']."</td><td>".$results['prof_name']."</td><td>".$results['designation']."</td><td>".$results['experience']."</td><td>".$results['prof_email_id']."</td><td>".$results['college_name']."</td><td>".$results['subject_name']."</td> ");

     echo(" <td><center><input type= 'submit' name='assign' value= 'Assign' /> </td>"); 

    /* echo(" <td><center><input type= 'hidden' name='prof_id' value='prof_id' /> </td>"); */

    echo("</p></tr>");
                }
    echo("</table></form>"); 
}

        else
        { 
            echo "<br> No matches found.";
        }

mysql_close($id_link);


?>

Here's **assignastemp.php**:<?php
include('connectionfile.php');

$prof_id= $_POST['prof_id'];  

 echo("</p> Professor ID: $prof_id"); 
mysql_close($id_link);


?>
```

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: Can you post your form html code? Where is the form being generated -- in the same file that it is being submitted to?

Comment: You need to POST the data in a form with POST method to read it as $_POST. POST can't be sent in the URL (that's the GET method).

Comment: Yea post your code, or else we will not know what the problem is

Comment: okay, i posted the code. it may have errors i don't know of, sorry for that and thank you in advance. Just a beginner.

Comment: is what i'm asking for possible? Is there any other way i can pass prof_id to a php file without having it taken as input in the previous html form (i mean the form that leads to the current form)? Please help me asap...

Comment: where is you input field in the form you want to submit?

Comment: @Toretto that is what my problem is. I'm not taking it as input, i'm just catching the value of prof_id in search.php and wanted to send it through to assignastemp.php.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching parameters at the end of your url like: `?prof_id=$query` sends them through `GET`, and thus you can only access the value through `$_GET['prof_id']` or `$_REQUEST['prof_id']`; There's a difference between `POST` And `GET`, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).

Comment: pkay, but i think i also need post there. can i get and post the same value in two different variables and use them differently in the same file?

Comment: @Pals with the form you have right now (the one with `method=post`), you'll send the `prof_id` through `GET` and the form items through `POST`. Just make the names are different for all of them, and it should work.

Comment: Nope, i tried many things, didn't work. Had to finish it asap. So i figured i'd take the prof_id as input again in one of my files. Problem solved! Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of a way (form) in HTML to submit data through, using `POST` method, in order to be able to fetch the data entered by using `$_POST[...]`.

Comment: yes, i've used the post method